# Flask-Principal, Flask-Login, remember_me and identity_loaded

Tags: python, flask, identity, flask-login, flask-principal

I work on a Flask app with Flask-Login and Flask-Principal and everything works fine so far except the remember me function of Flask-Login.

Actually the remember me function works on the Flask-Login side, but the idenity_loaded function of Flask-Principal doesn't get triggered.

When I log the calls of @login_manager.user_loader and @identity_loaded.connect is see both getting called when I log in, but when I close the browser and start it again, just the @login_manager.user_loader gets called. So my user gets basically logged in but gets no roles.

Flask-Login has a closed [Issue #19](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/issues/19) on GitHub but it actually doesn't answer my question :-/

Has anybody an idea how to react when the user get loaded from a cookie?

Comment: Which version of Flask-Login are you using ?

Comment: Flask==0.10.1, Flask-Principal==0.4.0, Flask-Login==0.2.11 and Python 3.4.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On before_request, `flask-principal` runs the identity_loaders one at a time until any identity is found.
If it doesn't find any identity, `identity_loaded` won't be called.

The first identity_loader is always the session loader by default.

When you restart the browser, the session will be gone, so `flask-principal` can't load any identity thus your `identity_loaded` callback won't be called. But you're still logged in because `flask-login`'s cookie 'remember_token' expires in 31 days.

So, to get rid of this idiosyncrasy, you can add new `identity_loader`, which will only run when session expires.

```
principal = Principal(app)

@principal.identity_loader
def load_identity_when_session_expires():
    if hasattr(current_user, 'id'):
        return Identity(current_user.id)
```